# Add a new column in win7 explorer?

Tags: c#, windows-7

I would like to create a new column for the detail view of the windows7 explorer. Actually I don't even know what to search for or if it even is possible.

Anyone ever tried something like that or could give me a hint what I should look for?

Mockup:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/974862/tempPublic/mockup.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible in Win7 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/thread/3653a52f-362c-4d4a-bc1c-7fa72d3e1263/

Comment: Oh, that sucks. Thanks for the answer. :(

Answer (score 1):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/features.html) had such a feature up to windows XP. It seems, this is no [longer possible since windows vista/7](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsMessageId=2424439&dsForumId=4061).